# Выведите на экран пять строчек, в первой строке четыре пробела и одна звездочка,

Tags: javascript, массивы, условия

Введите с экрана  число, например, 5. Выведите на экран пять строчек, в первой  строке четыре пробела и одна звездочка, во второй – три пробела и 
две звездочки и т.д. В последней -  пять звездочек.

```
Должно получиться:                      В моей программе:
        *                               * * * * *
      * *                               * * * *
    * * *                               * * *
  * * * *                               * *
* * * * *                               *
```

Как исправить?

```js
var n = prompt('Ведите число');
var mas = [];
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++){
    document.write((mas[i] = []) + '</br>');
    for (var j = 0; j < n; j++){
        if (j+i>n-1) {
            document.write( mas[i][j] = '     ');
        }else{
            document.write( mas[i][j] = '  * ');
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8"/> <!-- преобразование кодировки -->
    <title>Таблица</title> 
   </head>
      <body>
 
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var res = '', n = p = prompt('Ведите число');
while (p--) {
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        res += (i < p) ? ' ' : '*';
    res += '\r\n';
}
console.log(res);
```